# How do you overload a variadic template function?

Tags: templates, c++11

These are member functions of a template class:

```
template<class Function_T, class Data_T,typename... Args>
```

I have twotemplate functions:

```
void execute(Data_T&, Args&...);
void execute(Data_T&);
```

The problem is that if I don't declare my object with a variadic type for 'Args...' EVEN if I am calling the second function, it won't compile. Why does Args... need a type if it is not used? Shouldn't the template generator realize this? It requires the developer to pass a type (any type) in, despite the variable never actually being touched.

EXAMPLE CODE: (ignore the 'works')

http://pastebin.com/E1xsc6iS

http://pastebin.com/FxjVzuCm

Comment: Do you have a complete non working example ? [Here is a working version of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17310b106e7c1c48)

Comment: Show us the full signatures including `template`.

Comment: @quantdev Maybe because this is in a template class. I call ref(args...) in the one that take sin args, but not inthe other.

Comment: @user3816764 : show the complete code : how you call you functions, and what is the exact compilation error. I have the feeling that your issue has nothing to do with overloading.

Comment: I've added a much simpler that demonstrates the issue to the original quesiton.

Comment: I've also edited the question to be more accurate, as the issue was not ref, but in fact that I was declaring <int> and not <int, int> - for some reason it requires I give Args... a type, even if the non-Args... overloaded function is called.

Comment: Specialize the class for the case of only one argument. [Like this](http://rextester.com/LPW89129)

Comment: I see. I didn't realize you could specialize a class that way. If you 'Answer The Question' I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a partial specialization for your class, for the case of no `Args`:

```
template<class Data_T,typename... Args>
class tclass
{
public:
    // Two overloads
    void example(Data_T&, Args&...);
    void example(Data_T&);
};

template <class Data_T> 
class tclass<Data_T>
{
public:
    // One overload
    void example(Data_T&);
};
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/LPW89129)